# Python Pandas: How to get the maximum value per peak in multiple cycles

Tags: python, dataframe, max

I am importing data from a machine that has thousands of cycles on it. Each cycle lasts a few minutes and has two peaks in pressure that I need to record. One example can be seen in the graph below.

[image]

In this cycle you can see there are two peaks, one at 807 psi and one at 936 psi. I need to record these values. I have sorted the data so i can determine when a cycle is on or off already, but now I need to figure out how to record these two maxes. I previouly tried this:

```
df2 = df.groupby('group')['Pressure'].nlargest(2).rename_axis (index=['group', 'row_index'])
```

to get the maxes, but realized this will only give me the two largest values  which in some cycles happen right before the the peak.

In this example dataframe I have provided one cycle:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Pressure' : [100,112,114,120,123,420,123,1230,1320,1,23,13,13,13,123,13,123,3,222,2303,1233,1233,1,1,30,20,40,401,10,40,12,122,1,12,333]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The peak values for  this should be 1320, and 2303 whilke ignoring the slow increase to these peaks.

Thanks for any help!

(This is also for a ton of cycles, so i need it to be able to go through and record the peaks for each cycle)

Comment: An xckd is relevant here: https://xkcd.com/1425/ ... this probably can't be done in a couple of lines of code unless we can be sure that these peaks always conform to some pattern. For example, is it good enough to look for the largest two values such that the values on either side of them are smaller? This is a heuristic that will fail if, for example, it's possible for the higher peak to be a "twin-peak".

Comment: Not sure what an xckd is. And no there will not be "twin peaks"

Comment: Maybe you could also filter on only positive derivative values if you are getting too many false positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I had a go, using the simple heuristic I suggested in my comment.

```
def filter_peaks(df):
    df["before"] = df["Pressure"].shift(1)
    df["after"]  = df["Pressure"].shift(-1)
    df["max"] = df.max(axis=1)
    df = df.fillna(0)
    return df[df["Pressure"] == df["max"]]["Pressure"].to_frame()

filter_peaks(df) # test one application
```

If you apply this once to your test dataframe, you get the following result:

[image]

You can see, that it almost doesn't work: the value at line 21 only needed to be a little higher for it to exceed the true second peak at line 8.

You can get round this by iterating, ie., with `filter_peaks(filter_peaks(df))`. You then do end up with a clean dataframe that you can apply your `.nlargest` strategy to.

**EDIT**
Complete code example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Pressure' : [100,112,114,120,123,420,123,1230,1320,1,23,13,13,13,123,13,123,3,222,2303,1233,1233,1,1,30,20,40,401,10,40,12,122,1,12,333]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def filter_peaks(df):
    df["before"] = df["Pressure"].shift(1)
    df["after"]  = df["Pressure"].shift(-1)
    df["max"] = df.max(axis=1)
    df = df.fillna(0)
    return df[df["Pressure"] == df["max"]]["Pressure"].to_frame()

df2 = filter_peaks(df) # or do it twice if you want to be sure: filter_peaks(filter_peaks(df))
df2["Pressure"].nlargest(2)
```

Output:

```
19    2303
8     1320
Name: Pressure, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I added this to my data and im not even sure what it does, its just giving me max columns but none of the values are the max

Comment: Is there simply a way to get the max value of every 10 or so rows?

Comment: @SeanK22 What do you mean? I will add some code to complete the task.

Comment: Okay sorry I am new with Python I see what you are saying, this worked for 1 cycle, now i have to figure out how to apply it to the whole spreadsheet so it will give me these two maxes for each cycle. Thanks for the help and time!